# How to center an svg <pattern> inside a larger responsive container at all possible widths?

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-pattern

I have a responsive SVG container and I need my `<pattern>` to appear centered on every situation.

I mean:

- The `<pattern>` triangle should be centered at all possible widths
- And the space on left/right must repeat the triangle `<pattern>`

Is this possible? I know it's possible dynamically recalculating the pattern position with JS. But I would like to do it using `svg` properties only.

```css
.mySvg1 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.mySvg2 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.mySvg3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

span {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

.myDiv1 {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="myDiv1">
   SEE THAT THE TRIANGLE IS <span>NOT</span> CENTERED. I WOULD LIKE IT TO ALWAYS BE CENTERED
 </div>

<div>
  <svg class="mySvg1">
    <defs>
      <pattern 
        id="wave"
        width="150"
        height="50"
        patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      >
        <path d="M 0 50 l 75 -50 l 75 50" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#wave)"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div>
  <svg class="mySvg2">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#wave)"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div>
  <svg class="mySvg3">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#wave)"/>
  </svg>
 </div>
```

**EXTRA:**

It's easy to do it with `background-image`. I would like to do the same using `<svg>` only. Is this possible?

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.myDiv1 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 -2 150 52"><path d="M 0 50 l 75 -50 l 75 50" stroke="black" /></svg>');
  background-position: center;
}

.myDiv2 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 -2 150 52"><path d="M 0 50 l 75 -50 l 75 50" stroke="black" /></svg>');
  background-position: center;
}

.myDiv3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 -2 150 52"><path d="M 0 50 l 75 -50 l 75 50" stroke="black" /></svg>');
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  SEE THAT THE TRIANGLE IS ALWAYS CENTERED
</div>

<div class="myDiv1">
</div>

<div class="myDiv2">
</div>

<div class="myDiv3">
</div>
```

Comment: if you mean center from `<div>` you need to add `display:block; margin:auto;` to svg css. else i don't understand.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini he want to have with SVG the same output he did with CSS at the last snippet

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea where you need to:

1. set a big width to the rect considering the width of path (an odd multiplier of the width of the path)
2. you make the width of the pattern using percentage (`100/n` where `n` is the multiplier). You also remove `patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`
3. You place the `rect` at `50%` and you translate it back with `50%` to have it in the middle

In other words, we make the rect very big and we center it inside the SVG. The odd multiplier is to make sure the center of rect is the centre of a triangle and not the *between* two triangles.

```css
.mySvg1 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.mySvg2 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.mySvg3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

span {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

.myDiv1 {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

rect {
  transform:translate(-50%);
  transform-box:fill-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv1">
   SEE THAT THE TRIANGLE IS <span>NOT</span> CENTERED. I WOULD LIKE IT TO ALWAYS BE CENTERED
 </div>

<div>
  <svg class="mySvg1">
    <defs>
      <pattern 
        id="wave"
        width="9.1%"
        height="50"
      >
        <path d="M 0 50 l 75 -50 l 75 50" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect x="50%" y="0" width="1672" height="100%" fill="url(#wave)" />
  </svg>
</div>

<div>
  <svg class="mySvg2">
    <rect x="50%" y="0" width="1672" height="100%" fill="url(#wave)"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div>
  <svg class="mySvg3">
    <rect x="50%" y="0" width="1672" height="100%" fill="url(#wave)"/>
  </svg>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting idea. Where did the value `9.1%` come from? Does that come from `150/1672 = 8.97%` ? as in `(pattern width / big container width)`.

Comment: @cbdeveloper it's 150/1650 = 9.09% but since there is the stroke-width I have added this to the total to have 150*11 + 2*11 = 1672

Comment: @cbdeveloper you can keep the width 1650, the difference isn't very relevant